# Optimize resizing picture on a button with PIL

Tags: image, button, tkinter, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

self.image2Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(Tk):
def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.variables()
    self.makeUI()
def variables(self):
    self.buttonlist = []
    self.font = font.Font(family = "Consolas", size = 12, weight = "bold")
def makeUI(self):
    self.title("Changing font")
    self.geometry("300x300")
    self.minsize(200, 200)
    self.maxsize(1000, 1000)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)        
    self.buttonlist.append(Button(self, height = 2, width = 4, font = self.font))
    self.buttonlist[0].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W+E+S+N, padx = 2, pady = 2)        
    self.update()
    self.image2 = Image.open("1.png")
    self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image2.resize((self.buttonlist[0].winfo_width(), self.buttonlist[0].winfo_height()), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    self.buttonlist[0].configure(image = self.image)
    self.buttonlist[0].bind("<Configure>", self.changeimage)

def changeimage(self, *args):
    self.update()
    #use smaller size
    x = self.buttonlist[0].winfo_width()
    y = self.buttonlist[0].winfo_height()
    x = x if x < y else y
    self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image2.resize((x, x), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    self.buttonlist[0].configure(image = self.image)

def main():
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem:
The code works, the problem is that the program is slow on a quite powerful PC. It is making unnecessary calculations. My image is called "1.png".I don't know if I'm using the right approach.

Comment: Could you show us your '1.png'? I tried your program and it performs well on my PC. Opening a picture takes 0.04 seconds, and a resize (when resizing the application) takes 0.03 seconds typically. I tested with a 27k JPG image.

Comment: you could open image only once.

Comment: I use a 60kb png. furas good point! in the code there is the self.image2 and I forgot to use it. Michiel it is not unbearably slow, but not exactly smooth either. When you resize the window the image fails to follow smoothly. Is there no better nicer solution to this problem ?